# Different filters to receive all commits from query

Tags: r, git, github-api

I try to collect all commits from this api query:

```
https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=%22sentiment%22&per_page=100&page=200
```

However the limit is until 1000.

Here the code I try:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httpuv)
library(httr)

# Can be github, linkedin etc depending on application
oauth_endpoints("github")

# Change based on what you 
myapp <- oauth_app(appname = "name",
                   key = "insert_key", #please set your key and below the secret
                   secret = "insert_secret")

# Get OAuth credentials
github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"), myapp)

# Use API
gtoken <- config(token = github_token)

df_all <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 4))
names(df_all) = c("items_url", "items_sha", "items_commit_url", "items_commit_message")

for (i in 1:1406) {
  getURL = paste0("https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=%22sentiment%22&per_page=100&page=", i)
  req <- GET(getURL, gtoken)

  char <- rawToChar(req$content)
  df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(char)
  
  df_iteration <- data.frame(items_url = df$items$url, items_sha = df$items$sha, items_commit_url = df$items$commit$url, items_commit_message = df$items$commit$message)
  
  df_all <- rbind(df_all, df_iteration)

}
```

The total number of commits as you can see [here](https://github.com/search?q=%22sentiment%22&type=commits) is 140,306

Is there any alternative to use additional query parameters to receive all results? Or an alternative way